# How to place Compound drawable on top left of Text View

Tags: android, drawable, textview, compound-drawables

We can set compound drawables for textview as below using `drawableLeft`  or `setCompundDrawables` but using this its only possible to place the drawable on left / right / top / bottom.But i want to put drawables only at top-left and top-right of the Textview.
How can i do that ?

Comment: Already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267352/align-top-of-image-to-top-of-textview)