# Add drawable to EditText's top|left corner

Tags: android, android-edittext, drawable

I know that in Android we can use function setCompoundDrawables(..) to add drawable.

My problem is that my EditText is multy-lines and i want to put drawable in EditText's top|left corner. But using at setCompoundDrawables() function,  only give choice to put drawable in specific side.

Is it possibility at Android API to Do it?

Comment: Check this one - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: You can replace the `setCompoundDrawables(..)` with `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` like so -> `EditTextId.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, myIcon, 0, 0);`

Comment: What value i can put in myIcon? i know that is int.. between which values i can choose?

Comment: `myIcon` is just an example, but you can put the same, as you did in the `setCompoundDrawables(..) ` method, if you paste the code you got I can help you on it. :)

Comment: I found . int = the drawble id.

Comment: Ok, so try it on and see if it helps you ;-)

Comment: `myIcon ` is the drawable resource that you want to add in the `EditText`.

Comment: it's Not work. It's active like setCompoundDrawables(..)

Comment: What do you mean it's active - (do you mean it's acting like ..) ?

Comment: yes.. it's what i mean. it's dont give dynamism of drawable location into EditText

Comment: Did you try this one: `EditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawableIdOfThePicture), null);`

Comment: yes. its what i do first.

Answer (score 5):

Seems it's impossible to do it with only `EditText` / `TextView` without anyside effect and additional views (I've provided the way at the end, but it needs more work with image and can be not applicable for every phone, because of different edit text backgorunds depending of manufature). The same question have been asked already many times: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267352/align-top-of-image-to-top-of-textview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726583/how-to-place-compound-drawable-on-top-left-of-text-view) for example.

Per my understanding the easiest and fastests way might be not as suggested in above questions (by usage of `RelativeLayout`), but just using `FrameLayout` the following way (You'll have 2 views vs 3 view using `RelativeLayout`+`ImageView`):
Make your icon 9patch (using [9patch tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)). E.g. you have the following icon initially:

[image: original icon]

Then You can convert it to the following one:

[image] (You can see black pixels which shows area to be stretched with view and areas for content)

Using the following xml:

```
    <!-- Main activity layout -->
    <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Edit text with drawable at top left -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_9patch">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:hint="Enter text"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Gives the following result (I've added multiple lines of text):

[image: result image]

Moreover, it's even possible to comply the task with only `EditText` (but You might loose default EditText background which might not be good, however You can include it into your ning-patch image; but it will still be the same on all phones instead of *native* one).

The following xml also works fine:

```
<!-- Main activity layout -->
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Edit text with drawable at top left -->
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:hint="Enter text"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_9patch" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Give the following result (note that default frame for edit has disappeared):
[image: single view appearance]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/map_mark"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/scale_10"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:text="TEXT HERE"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```