# Android align drawable left to the first line of my textView

Tags: android, textview, drawable, vertical-alignment

I have a textView in which I put some text (obviously) and a Drawable left. Unfortunately, when I use phones with small screens like a Samsung Galaxy Y, instead of just a single line, the text runs over to a second line. (which is fine). However, the drawable that I set now aligns itself to the center of the textview, and not on the left of the first line.

I want my drawable to stay aligned to the first line of text in my textview, no matter how many lines of text, my textview holds. Is there a way to do this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

my implementation is pretty straightforward

```
...
tv.setCompoundDrawables(drawableLeft, null, null, null);
```

where my drawableLeft is the image from my drawable folder.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi A.A, i updated my post, although there's really not much code to post. my implementation is your run-of-the-mill setCompoundDrawables to a TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a drawable like a separate view (ie ImageView) and not to set it as a tag in a TextView. Using that will grant you more control over the drawable/ImageView it self.

Comment: Hi Aksiom, I realize that, altho I wouldn't want to create a relative layout with a text and an image. I'm trying to find a way to make the drawableLeft work. But thank you for you suggestion. Maybe if I dont think of a good solution, I'll just revert to this one. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to align a `Drawable` to the top of your `TextView` you can use a custom Drawable that wraps the `Drawable` you want to show. Then, override the method `onDraw(Canvas)` in your custom Drawable and translate the `Canvas` to manipulate the position of your Drawable.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906636/710990) for an example.