# How to align drawableLeft to top instead center in android TextView?

Tags: android, textview

In `TextView` I set `drawableLeft` where the `drawable` is showing from center. I need to align the `drawableLeft` with top inside `TextView` like this image.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Not simply. There's no `drawableTopLeft`. So, to achieve what you want, either use a separate ImageView or make a new control which extends TextView.

Comment: use BitmapDrawable.setGravity method,  also make sure your drawable bounds height is equal to textview height

Comment: @FrankN.Stein you are may be right. Could you please give some elaboration about custom controls.

Comment: @Sharif What is your text view height? That have constant height?

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki TextView height is not constant. It will grow as text size grow.

Comment: It's a broad argument. Here's how Lars Vogel explains that: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html and this is the official reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: @Sharif if your textview height have constant value like 50dp, you can create a .png file with height=50 and then set your image to above half of .png file(height 25dp above). if NO, you can use from this trick, but with Ninepatch. I hope this be useful.

Comment: It's quite simple using just XML, see my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

Use SpannableString and ImageSpan to achieve this.

```
String msg=" "+"haii";
ImageSpan mImageSpan== new ImageSpan(mContext, R.drawable.icon);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString(msg);
text.setSpan(mImageSpan, 0, 1, 0);
mTextView.setText(text);
```

the extra space in the string variable is replaced by the icon.

Comment: Lovely solution. But both icon and text are not on same gravity. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Try removing fontPadding on TextView.

Comment: This is not a generic solution, what if I need drawable at the end, as we do with `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, drawable, null)`

Answer (score 10):

I think it's even easier than all the answers above: You only need to do this:

```
public class TopGravityDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

    public TopGravityDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(res, bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int halfCanvas = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        int halfDrawable = getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0, -halfCanvas + halfDrawable);
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

And then

```
 final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mTitle.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
 icon = new TopGravityDrawable(mTitle.getResources(), bitmap);
 title.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);
```

Remember this only works properly with **LEFT** and **RIGHT** compound drawables

Comment: You should use `title.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);` instead

Answer (score 7):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906636/710990).

You can align a compound-Drawable to the top (or bottom) by creating a custom Drawable that wraps your Drawable, and then manipulate the drawing of your custom Drawable by overriding the method `onDraw(Canvas)`.

The sample below is the simplest possible example. This aligns the image to the top, but you can also make it align to the bottom, left or right of the TextView by implementing the required logic in the `onDraw(Canvas)`-method. You might also want to build in a margin in the `onDraw(Canvas)`, to make your design implementation pixel perfect.

Sample usage:

```java
GravityCompoundDrawable gravityDrawable = new GravityCompoundDrawable(innerDrawable);
// NOTE: next 2 lines are important!
innerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, innerDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), innerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
gravityDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, innerDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), innerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
mTextView.setCompoundDrawables(gravityDrawable, null, null, null);
```

Sample code:

```
public class GravityCompoundDrawable extends Drawable {

    // inner Drawable
    private final Drawable mDrawable;

    public GravityCompoundDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        mDrawable = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int halfCanvas= canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        int halfDrawable = mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;

        // align to top
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0, -halfCanvas + halfDrawable);
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use it to align text and left drawable to left of textview

Answer (score 4):

you can do like this:

```
public class DrawableTopLeftTextView extends TextView {

    public DrawableTopLeftTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawableTopLeftTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawableTopLeftTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getText())) {

            Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();

            if (drawables != null) {

                Drawable drawableLeft = drawables[0];

                if (drawableLeft != null) {

                    Paint.FontMetricsInt fontMetricsInt = getPaint().getFontMetricsInt();
                    Rect bounds = new Rect();
                    getPaint().getTextBounds((String) getText(), 0, length(), bounds);
                    int textVerticalSpace = Math.round(bounds.top - fontMetricsInt.top);
                    int offset = (getHeight() - drawableLeft.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2 - textVerticalSpace - getPaddingTop() / 2;
                    drawableLeft.setBounds(0, -offset, drawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawableLeft.getIntrinsicHeight() - offset);
                }
            }
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a purely XML solution then you can use an inset drawable to re-position your desired drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/actual_image_to_be_shown"
    android:insetTop="-32dp" />
```

You might have to play around with the inset value depending on your scenario. Then just use this XML drawable in your TextView drawableLeft/Start definition.

Comment: If you're going to give me a down vote, at least tell me why you don't like this solution.

Comment: Hard-coded values don't work with dynamic text. The negative offset depends on how many rows of text there are + the `fontSize` and other properties of the `TextView`. It's a neat hack though for single-line.

Comment: Without downvote but maybe the reason for them: Quote: "You might have to play around with the inset value depending on your scenario" => that means for textviews with dynamic length it is not a solution or at least not the best one

Answer (score 0):

Your can use by this way. May it can helpful you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text=" Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want to follow this way as in this way we have to use nested layout.

Comment: The outer RelativeLayout is completely useless. AND `fill_parent` is deprecated since API Level 8 included. Use `match_parent`, instead

Comment: @androidcodehunter it's either nested layouts or custom code, we need to take some kind of hit :( I always prefer an XML-only solution if it's reasonably good, which this is properly implemented (you can solve it with a simple horizontal `LinearLayout`). By the way you don't even need nesting if you use `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, but it's still 2 views.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
class MyTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : AppCompatTextView(context, style) {
    private val leftDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.checkmark)

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        setBulletPoint(compoundDrawables[0], canvas)
    }

    private fun setBulletPoint(drawableLeft: Drawable?, canvas: Canvas?) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            leftDrawable?.let { drlft ->
                if (lineCount == 1) {
                    setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drlft, null, null, null)
                } else {
                    val buttonWidth = drlft.intrinsicWidth
                    val buttonHeight = drlft.intrinsicHeight
                    val topSpace = abs(buttonHeight - lineHeight) / 2
           
                    drlft.setBounds(0, topSpace, buttonWidth, topSpace + buttonHeight)
                    canvas?.apply {
                        save()
                        drlft.draw(canvas)
                        restore()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```