# Add drawable starting of multiline text view

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-drawable

Need to add Quote as a drawable in multiline text like below mentioned screen. Like you can see quote is in a starting of multiline text and next line text is just starting from the below to the quote.

[image: Quote(drawable) should be starting of text in Textview and]
[image]

I need to use TextView to achieve this and quote should be a drawable.

If I am using drawableLeft property of TextView Its showing like below mentioned image.

[image]

```
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!\nHello World!\nHello World!\nHello World!"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_quote"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_quote"/>
```

Comment: this link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603607/how-to-align-drawableleft-to-top-instead-center-in-android-textview

Comment: This is not what i required.If you see the image properly. Next line text should start exactly from starting of drawable.This all required with one textview with multi line text.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a SpannableString to add the drawable :

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.ic_quote);
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("*" + myTextView.getText()); // "*" will be replaced by your drawable

int start = 0; // the start index, inclusive
int end = 1; // the end index, exclusive
int flag = 0;
spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, start, end, flag);

myTextView.setText(spannableString);
```

And in your layout :

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/myTextView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Hello World!\nHello World!\nHello World!\nHello World!"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `android:gravity="top"`

if it didnt work then go with negative margin like this

```
android:drawablePadding="-20sp"
```

Another alternative way is to take an `ImageView` beside  `TextView` inside `LinearLayout` so you can apply gravity

Comment: This is not what i required.If you see the image properly. Next line of text should start exactly from starting and same time below of the drawable.This all required with one textview with multi line text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpannableStringBuilder.

```
 val spannableText = SpannableStringBuilder("*Your text!").apply {
            val imageSpan = ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.your_icon)
            setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
 }
 textView.setText(spannableText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

The symbol * will be raplaced witn your icon.