# TextView set DrawableRight/Left... alignment

Tags: android, textview

I have few TextViews with drawable icons on left side. 
layout:

```
         <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/detail_padding">                  

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/status"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_status"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_status"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_description"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_description"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

If the text is too big, icon stand in the center of textview. I want to set icon aligned top of textview. Is it possible?

Comment: post your full xml layout

Comment: I suggest you to see this link answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267352/align-top-of-image-to-top-of-textview/28906636#28906636][1]

Comment: i want drawable set to left top edge of textview

Comment: @elya_a I suggest you to use `Text View` and `Image View` instead if you want Exact result even with bigger and small text data with `Align Top`.

Comment: @jaydroider thank you. I just hoped there is decision with only textview, but i have to use imageview

Comment: @elya_a I can give you example if you want to apply it ? it will bit easier for you. and if you know how to use then it's good.

Comment: @jaydroider i know how to do that. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must keep the layout as RelativeLayout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/detail_padding">                  
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_status"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_status"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_description"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_description"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: and what it gives me?

Comment: Flexibility to move items

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageId"
```

on the textview, and

```
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

on the image.

hope this helps.

Comment: It solved your problem ? you have accepted that one. I dont think it will work for you.

Comment: He want to `Align Top` that Drawable with `Text View1`. This will not do that thing.

Comment: i use linearlayout in same way

Answer (score 0):

Just use ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/detail_padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_status"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_status" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/drawable_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you will have to create a custom Drawable that wraps your Drawable, and then manipulate the drawing of your custom Drawable by overriding the method onDraw(Canvas).

There is a sample below. This aligns the image to the top, but you can also make it align to the bottom, left or right of the TextView by implementing the required logic in the onDraw(Canvas)-method. You might also want to build in a margin in the onDraw(Canvas), to make your design implementation pixel perfect.

Sample usage:

```
GravityTopDrawable gravityDrawable = new GravityTopDrawable(innerDrawable);
// NOTE: next 2 lines are important!
innerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, innerDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), innerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
gravityDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, innerDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), innerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
mTextView.setCompoundDrawables(gravityDrawable, null, null, null);
```

Sample code:

```
public class GravityTopDrawable extends Drawable {

    // inner Drawable
    private final Drawable mDrawable;

    public GravityTopDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        mDrawable = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int halfCanvas= canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        int halfDrawable = mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;

        // align to top
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0, -halfCanvas + halfDrawable);
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```